# Prevent .lib from loading DLL at runtime

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, runtime, dllimport

How would I prevent an import lib from loading the DLL it refers to at runtime until I call something like, say, `LoadLibrary`?

Comment: Don't link with the import library?

Comment: Linking is necessary, or you get reference errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need this:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Dec/02/Delay-Loading-a-DLL-with-a-Linker-Switch-in-Visual-Studio

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/273419/Dynamic-Libraries-with-Delayed-Function-Loading

Comment: Yep found that after some searching. However, [**This does not work for exported classes**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232912/how-to-use-delay-loading-with-a-dll-that-exports-c-classes). Still marking it as the answer, as it answered my question!