# Delay load python DLL when embedding python+numpy

Tags: python, c++, c, numpy, visual-c++

I am building a C++ application that will call python + numpy and I would like to DELAYLOAD the python dll. I use Visual Studio 2015 on Windows with 64 bit python 3.6. The DELAYLOAD works fine as long as I am not using numpy. As soon as I call `import_array()`, I can no longer build with DELAYLOAD option. The linker error is

> LNK1194   cannot delay-load 'python36.dll' due to import of data symbol '__imp_PyExc_ImportError'; link without /DELAYLOAD:python36.dll.

Here is my code:

```
// Initialize python
Py_Initialize();

// If I remove this line, I am able to build with DELAYLOAD
import_array();
```

Is there any way to make delay load possible when using numpy?

Alternative question: is it possible to create and fill with data a numpy.recarray without calling import_array()?

EDIT: I decided to get rid of import_array(). Here is some of the code that I use to initialize Python:

```
    if (!Py_IsInitialized())
    {
        // Initialize Python
        Py_Initialize();

        // Initialize threads
        PyEval_InitThreads();

        // Needed for datetime
        PyDateTime_IMPORT;

        // Needed to avoid use of Py_None, Py_True, and Py_False;
        // which cause inability to use DELAYLOAD
        HMODULE pythonDll = GetModuleHandle(L"python36.dll");
        if (pythonDll == nullptr)
        {
            throw gcnew NotSupportedException(L"GS_ERR_CannotInitialize");
        }
        PythonHelper::_pyNone = (PyObject*)GetProcAddress(pythonDll, "_Py_NoneStruct");
        PythonHelper::_pyTrue = (PyObject*)GetProcAddress(pythonDll, "_Py_TrueStruct");
        PythonHelper::_pyFalse = (PyObject*)GetProcAddress(pythonDll, "_Py_FalseStruct");
    }
```

Comment: Have you try two variants of build Release/Debug? Sometime this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find and Debug build of numpy, so using only Release LIB / DLL

Comment: How are you referencing numpy in your c++ app? Did you build it from source according to numpy instructions?

Comment: No, I am using the pre-built one from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy. Apparently, to build it a non-free fortran compilier is needed and I don't have one.

Comment: you can sign-up for beta ifort compiler which is available for at least few months

Comment: Are you writing an extension module, or embedding Python in an application? Probably not related to your issue, but did you recall including `Python.h` before any standard headers?

Comment: I am embedding Python in an application. Here is my includes:

    #pragma unmanaged
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Python.h"
    #include "datetime.h"
    #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
    #include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
    #pragma managed

    #include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is there any way to make delay load possible when using numpy?**

You might not be able to use `DELAYLOAD` with `import_array`:

1. You cannot delay load a DLL if data is imported from it ([official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa699254(v=vs.60).aspx)).
2. `import_array` imports the module where the function-pointer table is stored and points the correct variable to it ([official documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/c-api.array.html#miscellaneous)).

I doubt you are dealing with a case of *exporting classes* versus *exporting data members*.
See [this](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VC/microsoft.public.vc.language/2004-09/0456.html), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5233170/2707864), or [this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24499645/Delay-load-of-DLL-fails-because-of-static-member-variable.html).

Comment: Could you please give a link to the official documentation of numpy that says that is is impossible.

Comment: @AndreyBelykh - Numpy documentation would likely not mention issues with linking with specific linkers+flags, that would be too specific. But I updated the answer with the official documentation of MSVS+numpy that allows the conclusion.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I will have to avoid using import_array().

Answer (score 0):

This might also be caused by optimisation, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232912/how-to-use-delay-loading-with-a-dll-that-exports-c-classes).

You can also try to `Remove unreferenced code and data` in the project settings.